# Reading a properties file from the jar location

Tags: properties, jar, executable

I have an executable jar file which reads properties from a properties file. I have made the program work so that the properties file should be in the path where i am executing the jar [not in the directory where the jar is placed.]
I am doing something like this now:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("./sample.properties");
            if (stream != null) {
                prop.load(stream);
                    }
        }
```

This seems to work properly. I don't know what to do if i want to read the file from the directory where the jar exists. Can any one help me ?I tried removing the "/" but stil does not work

Answer (score 0):

The location of a JAR file containing class X is given by X.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().

Comment: It gives a url type object, in which i can call methods, gethost, getpath, but those give the full jar path, not the path in which jar is present

Comment: I agree. You'll have to figure out how to remove the final bit of the path. It isn't difficult. There are several methods available to help in the JDK.